# How to use the project templates?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. I have done a couple of smaller projects (2-3 pages, one table). I have a new project that is a great candidate for a shell app. It will have 20 pages, will consume data from a transactional database (cloud hosted) but also have an offline datastore (SQLite).  Right now, I just want to get the local version up and running. The template for Shell App generates an IDataService and a MockDataStore. That is a great place to start - but how do I have more than one table? I am a little confused how I would use that. What I would love to see is a template generated shell app that just adds another table (and corresponding list,detail views along with view models. For example, the simple "todo" sample but add a contact table to assign todo tasks to would be perfect. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean how to use templates in Shell App ? Maybe you can add image to show what your wants.

Comment: I think I figured out my own question. I was confused with the sample code from the Shell Template. I did some addition digging about the Dependency Service - which is what was really throwing me for a loop. The way the sample code is generated, the Interface is for a singleton table. I can't believe how much time I wasted figuring that out.

Comment: Hi , glad solved ! Take it easy. Just after getting familiar with Xamarin, it’s fine. You can share it in answer .

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps others new to Xamarin. When starting a new project and choosing anything other than the "blank template", the template generates a model (Item) and a services folder containing an Interface (IDataStore) and a MockDataStore. Being new to XAML in general, I spent a lot of time working on getting the UI to look like what I wanted it, learning about Shell navigation and similar topics. Finally it was time to include the data part of my project. Where I got stuck was trying to make sense of the boilerplate code. My understanding of DependencyService was for platform specific code (e.g. Android, iOS) and NOT data service dependency. Further, the templated code is a typed interface (IDataStore). The solution was fundamental - all that interface does is insure CRUD operations are available in whatever you use in a datastore. For me, simply changing IDataStore to not be typed as an Item, solved everything. It allowed me to keep the database layer abstracted away. In my little project, I completed my "MockDataStore" adding additional CRUD operations until I was ready for my real data operations. NOTE: if you generate the WEB API project from the template, it will make more sense - you can flip between your MockDataStore and actual data store.